# What does "Möhre" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does "Möhre" mean here? And where does this expression come from?

> Vielleicht sollte ich noch hinzufügen, dass unser Windows 7 PC über WLAN am Netz ist, und wir für die alte **XP-Möhre** ein Netzwerkkabel benutzen.

[Source](http://diablo3.ingame.de/forum/threads/1625943-Lag-bei-TCP-IP-Spielen-unter-Windows-7?p=24781892&viewfull=1#post24781892)

Comment: A computer running Windows XP. The use of _Möhre_ may be an interesting question, but the XP part is not, IMO.

Comment: The same construct why you call a crap car a *lemon* in English

Answer (score 23):

*Möhre* here refers to the old computer. Generally, any piece of equipment that is outdated (not in a nostalgic way) and often already insufficient can be referred to as a *Möhre*.

The word is short for *Mohrrübe* (carrot). *Gurke* (cucumber) can be used in just the same way.

Comment: *Gurke* is mainly used for vehicles. It can also be used as a verb in that case. *herumgurken* can mean *driving overly slow, being in the way, blocking others*. Sebastian Vettel was once criticized for calling slower cars *Gurken* after a Malaysia race.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: *Möhre* kenne ich aber auch primär von Mopeds.

Answer (score 1):

Gurke or Möhre is an synonym for an average item, nothing worth paying attention anymore.

An old computer, software or items which is not up to date anymore is just a normal none considerable thing.